# UrlRewriting exclude folders

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I currently have this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(folder1|folder2)/? index.php [NC,L]
```

But instead of setting folders included to rewrite to `index.php` i want to rewrite **all** folders to `index.php` *except* `folderx|foldery`.

How is this possiblie? Sorry I'm new at UrlRewriting.

Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(folderx|foldery) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/? index.php [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also exclude folders in  RewriteRule by using regex **not character** "?!"

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^((?!folderx|foldery).*)/?$ index.php [NC,L]
```